# Qt Creator closed because of a problem with the "CppTools" plugin

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I made a wrong manoeuvre on Qt MaintenanceTool so I uninstalled QtCreator and installed it again, and now when I launch Qt a window appears on which it's written the following message:" Qt Creator closed because of a problem with the "CppTools" plugin,temporarily disable the plugin ?"

Then I can't open or create a c project anymore.

Would you have any suggestion ?

Comment: what is *manoeuvre*?

Comment: to attempt something

Comment: I just upgraded QtCreator to the latest version on MacOS and have the same problem. Found nothing in the QtCreator issue tracker and forums...

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23916) and with the advice I got I managed to solve it. It was a problem with my user settings. You can start QtCreator with "temporary clean settings":

```
open <path-to>/Qt/Qt\ Creator.app --args -tcs
```

If that works, clear your Qt user settings persistently:

```
mv ~/.config/QtProject ~/.config/QtProject.bak
```

Now you have a blank slate, and might have to reconfigure your projects etc.

Note that this is for macOS, the commands will differ for other platforms.